# PHPbb froum can't change background logo color to gradient

Tags: html, css, phpbb3

I'm using phpbb3 for forum for my site. I added custob header there, it was easy, but now I want to set gradient.
I use [this gradient generator](http://www.display-inline.fr/projects/css-gradient/#startType=hex&startValue=47F7FE&endType=hex&endValue=3EC6DC)
It generated me following code:

```
background: #3EC6DC url("pah_to_my_logo.jpg") repeat-x top;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
/* Recent browsers */
background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top, left bottom,
    from(#47F7FE),
    to(#3EC6DC)
);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #47F7FE,
    #3EC6DC
);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #47F7FE,
    #3EC6DC
);
background: -o-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #47F7FE,
    #3EC6DC
);
background: linear-gradient(
    top,
    #47F7FE,
    #3EC6DC
);
```

I've replaced `.headerbar` css in `/styles/prosylver/theme/colours.css` on this code (`pah_to_my_logo.jpg` is my logo of course).
Now I see gradiented color, but dont'see my log. How can I compare it?
I tried something like:

```
background: url("pah_to_my_logo.jpg") linear-gradient(
    top,
    #47F7FE,
    #3EC6DC
);
```

but this doesn't works.
**UPDATE**
Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tp52c882/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to put something in the `<div>` or give it dimensions;

```
.gradient {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
```

If you want a background image aswell, you are out of luck the rules conflict. You would have to create a second `<div>` for that presentation.

Comment: height and width are set. So, should add my own div for it. I see.